# Why does "configure: error: zstd library not found" appear when I configure green plum, but I have downloaded zstd

Tags: greenplum

install greenplum 
 ./configure
problem: 
configure: error: zstd library not found
If you have libzstd already installed, see config.log for details on the
failure.  It is possible the compiler isn't looking in the proper directory.
Use --without-zstd to disable zstd support.

I try to install zstd 
1.pip install zstd   done  nothing problem
2.yum install zstd-devel      "No matching distribution found for zstd-deve"

when you  "./configure" ,it don't error

Answer (score 5):

Greenplum needs to compile and link against zstd. Looking at the command you tried (`yum install zstd-devel`), I am assuming you are using RHEL/CentOS 7. There is no package for zstd in the CentOS repos --- you'll need to install it from [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). It should look something like

```sh
yum install epel-release
yum install libzstd-devel
```

Comment: I downloaded the source file of zstd-master directly from GitHub and made it directly. The problem disappeared, I don't know what the hidden danger will be.

Comment: xml2-0.5-7.el7.x86_64                                                                                       
 libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64            you sea ,my libxml  >2.6.23  .but  Still wrong “library 'xml2' (version >= 2.6.23) is required for XML support    ”